# What those nodeJS options mean

Tags: node.js

I'm renting a 96 core, 360gb ram linux VM from GCP. My function is generating 100.000.000 combinations (array of items), and each gets passed into a fairly heavy function. I'm running `numberOfCores - 1` workers to divide the task into equal parts.

The instance is throwing different errors with different option values, but the common in all of them is: `JavaScript heap out of memory`.

I've had some playaround with those:

`--max-old-space-size`, `--max-semi-space-size`

The first option is the most popular, and as I see solves the problem most of the cases, but not in mine.

I'm trying to research all my possible options to solve this problem (as I can't believe 96 cores, and 360gb ram isn't enough), and I found some:

For worker:

- maxOldGenerationSizeMb
- maxYoungGenerationSizeMb
- codeRangeSizeMb
- stackSizeMb

For node (excluding the already mentioned ones):

- --v8-pool-size
- --huge-max-old-generation-size
- --stack-trace-limit

They aren't too well documented, and I would like to understand what each mean to solve my out of memory problem, and set them to maximize the hardware resource usage without crashing it.

Comment: Do you really need all combinations at once in RAM? Normally I only need to evaluate one combination at a time. Would that work? If so you can use either a generator or callback based code to evaluate one combination at a time. I have some permutation code I wrote some time back to test this idea if you are interested

Comment: My current implementation is to calculate all combinations (to have the overall length), get the number of cores available - 1, from those, calculate the number of elements to process for each core, split the big array into chunks (and splicing it at the same time), then start the workers with their own pieces. The error is usually thrown after the 10-15th worker is started. I would like to see your idea, maybe my thinking is wrong.

Comment: I presume you are generating combinations via a recursive function?

Comment: @GergőHorváth - did you have any luck? I have a 256gb server and am running into the same `out of memory` issue with my master node process and its `worker_thread`s

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I was having the same trouble with OOM errors on a linux box with 256gb of memory, and no tweaks of any of those values worked for me. Based on [this discussion](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32265#issuecomment-600026192), what ended up solving the `worker_thread` OOM errors for me was tweaking these limits:

```
sysctl -w kernel.threads-max=4194303
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=8388606
sysctl -w kernel.pid_max=4194303
```

And to persist them across reboot:

```
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
kernel.threads-max = 4194303
vm.max_map_count = 8388606
kernel.pid_max = 4194303
```

After stopping and restarting the main node process once those were applied, I did not see the OOMs.

Another interesting thing I found - the `max-old-space-size` param that you set when starting node is [inherited by all the worker_threads](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2809#issue-647046779) and you don't need to issue that same amount using the `resourceLimits. maxOldGenerationSizeMb` -- so I don't think you need to launch the 'master' script with a huge amount and then set the worker_threads to a smaller amount; I think you can just launch the master script with the same values you intend on giving to the `worker_thread`

Finally, FWIW, I was not able to set the max threads to more than the CPU core count with this configuration. I'm using [threadsjs](https://threads.js.org/) and a ThreadPool, not spawning the workers directly though.